# Trouble Accessing ta-lib.org

Tags: java, kotlin, finance, ta-lib, technical-indicator

I'm currently experiencing difficulties accessing http://ta-lib.org . For curl command, and I receive the following error:

```
curl http://ta-lib.org --show-error
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ta-lib.org
```

Is there any problem on my machine / country? Or does anyone have any info what happened?

I need a ta-lib for my kotlin project, can anyone recommend a library?

**EDIT:** https://ta-lib.github.io current pages

Comment: What is `ta-lib` ?

Comment: Talib is an open-source technical analysis library used by traders, investors and analysts to perform complex calculations on financial data and build trading strategies. The library is written in C language and provides more than 150 technical indicators and trading functions.

Comment: The DNS record for ta-lib.org is not answering.  Perhaps you need this: https://ta-lib.github.io/ta-lib-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right url is now https://ta-lib.github.io/ta-doc/
according to Mario Fortier, who's the author of the lib: https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python/issues/547#issuecomment-1311180938